# How to use Wingethandle in Robot framework

Tags: robotframework, autoit

I try to use this in Robot framework

> **@{Title} = Win get handle("[ACTIVE]")**

But It seem doesn't work.I need some Example for this command.

Please Help
Sorry for my poor Grammar

```
**ERROR**
Cannot set variable '@{Title}': Expected list-like value, got string.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running keywords, you don't use parentheses after the keyword to submit parameters. Instead use:

`${Title}=    Win Get Handle    [ACTIVE]`

The `[ACTIVE]` parameter is automatically submitted as a string.

Also, notice that I changed `@{Title}` into `${Title}`. That is because `@` denotes a list variable that expects a list return from the keyword. Apparently the `Win get handle` returns a String variable, which shall be assigned to a scalar `$`-denoted variable.

Lastly, I'm not sure if you're using `Win Get Handle` correctly. To my understanding the implementation for that keyword would return a handle to a window (a unique identifier to run further actions against it) rather than its title.